# Receiving java.lang.StackOverflowError on syncing gradle files in flutter

Tags: flutter, gradle, dart, synchronization

At the end it says "CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL " when I try to sync the project with gradle files,but I get the warning of java.lang.StackOverflowError.What does it mean?

I tried deleting the gradle files and cache.

I tired rebuilding the project.

I tried invalidate and restart cache.But still this is not going.

What is the fix?

```
re.java:232)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FreeListBlockStore$FreeListBlock.alloc(FreeListBlockStore.java:232)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FreeListBlockStore$FreeListBlock.alloc(FreeListBlockStore.java:232)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FreeListBlockStore$FreeListBlock.alloc(FreeListBlockStore.java:232)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FreeListBlockStore$FreeListBlock.alloc(FreeListBlockStore.java:232)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FreeListBlockStore$FreeListBlock.alloc(FreeListBlockStore.java:232)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FreeListBlockStore$FreeListBlock.alloc(FreeListBlockStore.java:232)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FreeListBlockStore$FreeListBlock.alloc(Fr
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FreeListBlockStore$FreeListBlock.alloc(FreeListBlockStore.java:232)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FreeListBlockStore$FreeListBlock.alloc(FreeListBlockStore.java:232)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FreeListBlockStore$FreeListBlock.alloc(FreeListBlockStore.java:232)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FreeListBlockStore$FreeListBlock.alloc(FreeListBlockStore.java:232)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FreeListBlockStore$FreeListBlock.alloc(FreeListBlockStore.java:232)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree
```

.
.

.
.
.
.
.
.
..
.

.

CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL in 4m 22s

Comment: Maybe try:

flutter pub cache repair &
cd <YOUR APP FOLDER> &
flutter clean

Answer (score 8):

I was hit with this error when I was trying to build my projects.

```
Failed to execute org.gradle.cache.internal.AsyncCacheAccessDecoratedCache$2@1204453a.
java.lang.StackOverflowError at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FreeListBlockStore$FreeListBlock.alloc(FreeListBlockStore.java:222)
```

Deleting the **journal-1** folder, from the path **/Users/UserName/.gradle/caches/journal-1** fixes this issue since it’s cause by corruption of entries in this folder **file-access.bin**, **journal-1.lock** and they are regenerated if not available.

credit to this website [Take care of your gradle home directory](https://jitinsharma.in/posts/take-care-of-your-gradle-home-directory)

Answer (score 1):

@D. Lucas...I think your solution kind of works because I did many things apart from what you said.Initially I closed android studio and in C:\Users\XX.gradle\caches cleared all the caches.The mistake I initially did was while the android studio opened I tried clearing the cache and that didnt delete all the files.

Then C:\Users\XX.gradle\wrapper\dists I deleted all the files

Opened flutter and ran flutter upgrade

and then as u said ran flutter pub cache repair

and Now it is fine

Thanks again @D. Lucas...It helped me

Answer (score 0):

Try :

> flutter get packages

maybe some packages are not installed or something.
hope that helps.